# How do exterior door seals prevent moisture infiltration if they're located on the inside of the door?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

I've got an exterior door that leaks cold air like the dickens.
I installed a vinyl door sweep like this one from home depot (pictured) on the bottom and the leakage problem was solved!

[image: Image of a door sweep]

A few months have passed and I've noticed the vinyl starting to wear and tear. I looked at the directions again and lo' and behold - I had installed the sweep on the *outside* and not the *inside* like the directions say.

This certainly makes sense from a wear perspective for my inner-swing exterior door - the sweep will no longer have to travel over the threshold when installed on the inside.

But if the sweep is installed on the interior, what's the right way to prevent moisture from getting below the door and wicking into the jamb, threshold, and door itself?

I've sealed those areas with waterproofing sealant, but I doubt that'll hold up to repeated abuse in this high traffic area.
I've also thought about installing a less robust brush sweep on the *outside* of the door and installing a more robust vinyl sweep on the *inside*, but that feels like a hack.

Comment: Oh - the door and the threshold sit at different angles unfortunately (as in, the gap at the bottom is bigger on one side than the other). So a door sweep like this one will not work (I've tried): https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cinch-36-in-White-Vinyl-U-Shape-Cinch-Slide-On-Under-Door-Seal-43336/205573049

I've done what I could to true up the door and the jamb, so the difference in the gap between one side and the other is smaller, but I wasn't able to completely fix the problem.

Comment: Home Depot links are geofenced. Can't be seen outside US [& possibly Canada]. Picture would be more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - edited!